# как отобразить второе окно в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

**При нажатии на кнопку в первом окне, нужно чтобы открывалось второе.** 
Помогите пожалуйста.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.resize(420, 499)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 201, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 261, 411, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 171, 191))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 40, 211, 101))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(SecondWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 420, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SecondWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

        self.show()


class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(420, 499)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 201, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("нажми")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 261, 411, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 171, 191))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 40, 211, 101))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 420, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)

    def show_window_2(self):
        self.w2 = SecondWindow()
        self.w2.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyWidget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> НИКОГДА не изменяйте модуль созданный в Qt Designerе !!!
>
> **WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


#class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
class Ui_SecondWindow(object): 
#    def __init__(self):
#        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
#        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.resize(420, 499)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 201, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton", self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton_2", self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 261, 411, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("label", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 171, 191))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 40, 211, 101))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("label_2", self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("lineEdit", self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("label_3", self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("lineEdit_2", self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel("label_4", self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_3)
        
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel("label_5", self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_4)
        
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton_3", self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        
        
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        '''
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(SecondWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 420, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SecondWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SecondWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)
#        self.show()
        '''

# First window
class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(420, 499)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 201, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("нажми")
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 261, 411, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 171, 191))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 40, 211, 101))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 420, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class SecondWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_SecondWindow):               # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('SecondWindow')   
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Choose a Number", "1", "2", "3", "4"])


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_FirstWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('FirstWindow')

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)

    def show_window_2(self):
        self.w2 = SecondWindow()
        self.w2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]